# No sound after select "Dummy output" in configurations->audio

Tags: sound, configuration, soundcard

I' just having problems with sound for a little while now since I selected dummy output, all other "outpus" in the menu disappear, and i dont have sound. I tried with some tutorials by now: about ALSA mixer, and i can't restore my original audio settings. I forgot to mention that before i selected dummy output, i was experimenting troubles with sound like: sound only via headphones. I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Go back into your sound preferences and select your audio card instead of the dummy driver.

Comment: yeah, that would work, but the little tricky business here is that the audio card no longer appear to select, in fact, the menu has gone Dummy output is the only option now. Thks anyway.